# No error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: asp.net, excel

In my application i am making user to upload the excel file.
While uploading the excel file i am getting this error  "**No error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005). at** ".
but not all the time this error is coming. sometime this error is coming.I am not able to trace when this error is occuring.
Plz help.

Comment: When you say 'uploading', what do you mean, exactly? E_FAIL is a COM error, are you trying to automate Excel to open the document?

Comment: I am saving the file in one folder and accesing that excel file by using oledbConnection and filling the dataset and cheking the columns names thats it

Comment: Any Help. I am not using any com components.

Answer (score 0):

**Only Temporary solution:-** 
1) If you try to upload same file name multiple times this problem will raise. So try to upload distinct file name every time.